# Count number of rows without using any aggregate functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to count the number of rows in a table with a single SQL query.

That query should not contain any aggregate function like `COUNT`.

Comment: Why do you need to do that? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Can you show are result are you expecting and what is your data ? Why cannot you use COUNT ?

Comment: Please explain why you would want to do that.

Comment: Thanks to all guys, i face these question in an interview, i could found the answers, interviewer asked me no aggregate function to be used like  count,max,min,rownumber().

Comment: I hope arin1405 & J0e3gan that answer excepted by the interviewer Thanks Guys

Comment: I hate when interviewers (or teachers etc) provide unrealistic examples/questions - I know it's in order to test "thinking outside the box", but then they should provide actual "outside the box" questions and not an artificial and unrealistic question :)

Comment: I Got 3 Answers,tough to select one there answers given by Allan,Arin,joe. Thanks to all guys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy way:

```
DECLARE @i INT = 0

SELECT @i = @i + 1
FROM <WHAT EVER>

SELECT @i AS RC
```

Fast, effective and no need for all sorts of sub queries as it requires only one run through the data :)

Comment: Except that your solution is not a single query.  Otherwise `SELECT 1 FROM YourTable;  SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;` comes to mind too.

Comment: Wrap it in an EXEC or similar and it's "technically" one query ;)

Comment: Also, at least with my database options, `RowCount` yields `Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 6  Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'RowCount'.` - whereas `[RowCount]` does what you expect.  Agreed - a very nice solution...but not within the constraints of the problem unfortunately.

Comment: I had the same "wrap it in an `EXEC`" thought when my mind quickly turned to `SELECT 1 FROM YourTable;  SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;` - but no dice. :}  Still, this is cool & clean enough from the no-aggregates perspective that I can't bring myself to downvote it. :D

Comment: Yea - RowCount is reserved keyword, changed it to RC instead.

Comment: Thanks to all guys, i face these question in an interview, i could found the answers, interviewer asked me no aggregate function to be used like  count,max,min,rownumber().

Comment: I hope arin1405 & J0e3gan that answer excepted by the interviewer Thanks Guys

Comment: Thanks Allan S. Hansen.

Comment: @Narenda: This is not a single-query solution; and `ROW_NUMBER` is not an [aggregate function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx) but rather a [ranking function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx); but maybe the interviewer didn't care about those distinctions either.  Like I said, I like this solution too (a lot actually)...but fit the constraints of your original problem statement it does not.

Answer (score 8):

I'm a little surprised nobody has mentioned this yet:

```
EXEC sp_spaceused @objname = N'MyTable', @updateusage = 'TRUE'
```

This will, among other things return the current count of records in the table.

This would also work in most cases:

```
SELECT rows 
FROM sys.partitions 
WHERE index_id IN (1,0) 
    AND object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'MyTable')
```

Answer (score 5):

The [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734(v=sql.100).aspx) *ranking* function will do the trick in a single query without using an aggregate function:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Row
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SomeColumn) Row
    FROM YourTable) output
ORDER BY Row DESC
```

Answer (score 4):

An `over()` function solves the problem.

```
select Column1,Column2, count(*) over() as testColumn from tablename
```

Comment: Not sure why this had a down vote, it worked beautifully - allows for a single query without the need for an aggregate

Answer (score 1):

COUNT THE NUMBER OF ROWS OF ITEMS.

```
SELECT MAX(EMPLOYEE_ID) FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY EMPLOYEE_ID DESC) EMPLOYEE_ID FROM MYCODE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since "single SQL query" has proven to be a loose requirement, consider what I thought of immediately...but dismissed as unfit (as I indicated in comments on @AllenSHansen's answer):

```
SELECT 1 FROM YourTable;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
SELECT MAX(Row) FROM 
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY anycolumn DESC) Row FROM tablename) output
```

but what is stopping you use Count()? prefer to use count().

Comment: `MAX` is also an aggregate function.

Comment: `SELECT TOP 1 Row FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY anycolumn DESC) Row FROM tablename) output ORDER BY Row DESC` takes the same basic approach...without using an aggregate function.

Comment: Thanks to all guys, i face these question in an interview, i could found the answers, interviewer asked me no aggregate function to be used like  count,max,min,rownumber().

Answer (score -1):

Here you may find one way to do that:

```
SELECT
   Total_Rows= SUM(st.row_count)
FROM
   sys.dm_db_partition_stats st
WHERE
    object_name(object_id) = 'Mytable' AND (index_id < 2)
```

Find a good discussion on it [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3849/retrieving-row-count-without-using-count-function).

Comment: As was pointed out with @Chethan's use of `MAX`, `SUM` is an aggregate function.  Otherwise this pretty much matches my answer...wherein the `SUM` is totally unnecessary.

Answer (score -2):

There are to ways to count records in a table:

1. Let the dbms count. You'd use an aggregate function for this, e.g. `select count(*) from mytable;`
2. You count. I.e. execute `select * from mytable;` and then count the records shown.

I would suggest the former method, but you seem to want to use the latter. Enjoy.

Comment: I don't quite understand the downvotes. In order to count the rows in a table you must aggregate the rows, be it directly  with `COUNT(*)` or indirectly with `COUNT(*) OVER ()` or the like. This is the only way to get the exact count (i.e. not an approximization from some system tables) with only one query from the DBMS. The other method is to select all rows and count yourself.

Answer (score -2):

Using `ROW_NUMBER()`, you will get the total number of rows in a table without using aggregate functions as the 2-step example below demonstrates.

### 1) Table & Data Setup

Example:

```
Create Table Dted (id int , name Varchar(20))

Insert into dted values (1,'aaa'),(2,'bbb'),(3,'ccc')

Select * from dted
```

Output:

```
id   name
1    aaa
2    bbb
3    ccc
```

### 2) Total Number of Rows

Example:

```
select top 1 ROW_NUMBER() over (order by id) as TotRows from dted order by TotRows desc
```

Output:

```
TotRows
3
```